# ASP.NET-MVC 2 DataAnnotations StringLength

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

Can I use the MVC 2 DataAnnotations to specify a minimum length for a string field?

Has anyone done this or have they created custom attributes and if so do you mind sharing the source?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you're using asp.net 4.0, you can use the StringLength attribute to specify a minimum length.

Eg:

```
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength=1)]
public string MyText { get; set; }
```

Comment: No we're not using 4.0 just yet and the way things happen here it won't be for a long time yet. :)

Comment: FYI.. If you "under-post" (meaning you don't post a form field called "MyText"), the StringLength validation on that property will be ignored. [Here's an article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html) explaining this scenario using a similar attribute (RequiredAttribute).

Answer (score 7):

Use a regular expression attribute. These are interpreted on the client side as well.

```
[RegularExpression(Regexes.MinStringLength)]
public string MyText { get; set; }
```

Where `Regexes.MinStringLength` is a static regular expression class. Inline would look like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.{5,10}$")] // valid five to ten characters
public string MyText { get; set; }
```

Comment: Regexes.MinStringLength seems to be home grown, perhaps you could put in an example that works without need for other definitions? Maybe [RegularExpression(".{1}")], changing 1 for whatever min length you want.

Comment: Sorry, that should read [RegularExpression(".{1,}")] - ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx